# Regex only first character to select?

Tags: regex

What im trying to achive is that select first character but only if its a-z or A-Z.

I found this: `^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9.,$;]+$` but problem is that if i have 
a544334 it select all string, and i want to select only first character.

Something like this `^G` so if i have G454 it will select only G.

Any suggestion?

Comment: `^[a-zA-Z](?=[a-zA-Z0-9.,$;]+$)`

Comment: that is it .. tnx :)

Answer (score 0):

`^[a-zA-Z]` is enough actually.

As suggested in comments, you can use a lookahead, but what would you do that if you don't care about the next chars ?